# DITA OpenToolkit 2.1.1 build.xml "BUILD FAILED" error when running ANT script

Tags: xslt, ant, dita, dita-ot

### DITA Output Goal

I want to add a custom CSS stylesheet to my DITA topic model with an ANT script (see the following code):

#### ANT Script Code

My ANT script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- ==================
  Web Output Custom CSS 
  ==================-->
<project name="grid_web_css"default="grids.grid_web_css" basedir=".">

    <property name="dita.dir" location="${basedir}${file.separator}..${file.separator}..${file.separator}.."/>
    <property name="css.output.dir" value="${dita.dir}${file.separator}projects${file.separator}css-projects${file.separator}ant-scripts${file.separator}out${file.separator}ex-ant-understanding-css"/>
    <property name="the.input.dir" value="${dita.dir}${file.separator}projects${file.separator}css-projects"/>
    <property name="css.source.dir" location="${dita.dir}${file.separator}projects${file.separator}css-projects${file.separator}shared-assets"/>
    <target name="grids.grid_web_css" depends="clean.grids.grid_web_css">
        <ant antfile="${dita.dir}/build.xml">
            <property name="args.input" location="${dita.dir}${file.separator}projects${file.separator}css-projects${file.separator}understanding_css.ditamap"/>
            <property name="input.dir" location="${the.input.dir}"/>
            <property name="output.dir" location="${css.output.dir}"/>
            <property name="transtype" value="html5"/>
            <property name="args.cssroot" location="${css.source.dir}"/>
            <property name="args.css" value="${css.source.dir}${file.separator}web-css-grids.css"/>
            <property name="args.csspath" value="${css.output.dir}/css"/>
            <property name="args.copycss" value="yes"/>
            <property name="processor" value="saxon"/>
            <property name="classpath" value="${dita.dir}${file.separator}lib${file.separator}saxon.jar"/>
        </ant>
        <copy todir="${css.output.dir}/css">
            <fileset dir="${css.source.dir}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean.grids.grid_web_css" description="remove the sample web output">
        <delete dir="${css.output.dir}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Problem

The directory is made and the build.xml file is found and executed, as per the terminal output below. Yet, nothing is actually generated within the directory, and I can't isolate the problem.

#### Terminal Output

```
lingeringcode@Linger:~/dita-ot-2.1.1$ ant -f '/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/ant_grid_web_css.xml' 
Buildfile: /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/ant_grid_web_css.xml

clean.grids.grid_web_css:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/out/ex-ant-understanding-css

grids.grid_web_css:

init:

dita2html5.init:

check-arg:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/out/ex-ant-understanding-css
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/temp/temp20151020094428144

log-arg:
     [echo] *****************************************************************
     [echo] * basedir = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts
     [echo] * dita.dir = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1
     [echo] * transtype = html5
     [echo] * tempdir = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/temp/temp20151020094428144
     [echo] * outputdir = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/out/ex-ant-understanding-css
     [echo] * clean.temp = true
     [echo] * DITA-OT version = 2.1.1
     [echo] * XML parser = Xerces
     [echo] * XSLT processor = Saxon
     [echo] * collator = JDL
     [echo] *****************************************************************
     [echo] #Ant properties
     [echo] #Tue Oct 20 09:44:29 CDT 2015
     [echo] args.copycss=yes
     [echo] args.css=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/shared-assets/web-css-grids.css
     [echo] args.csspath=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/out/ex-ant-understanding-css/css
     [echo] args.cssroot=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/shared-assets
     [echo] args.grammar.cache=yes
     [echo] args.input=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/understanding_css.ditamap
     [echo] args.logdir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/out/ex-ant-understanding-css
     [echo] args.xml.systemid.set=yes
     [echo] dita.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1
     [echo] dita.plugin.com.sophos.tocjs.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/com.sophos.tocjs
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.base.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.docbook.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.docbook
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.eclipsecontent.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.eclipsecontent
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.eclipsehelp.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.eclipsehelp
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.htmlhelp.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.htmlhelp
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.javahelp.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.javahelp
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.odt.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.odt
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.pdf2.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.pdf2
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.specialization.dita11.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.specialization.dita11
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.specialization.eclipsemap.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.specialization.eclipsemap
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.troff.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.troff
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.wordrtf.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.wordrtf
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.xhtml.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.xhtml
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.oasis-open.dita.v1_2.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.oasis-open.dita.v1_2
     [echo] dita.temp.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/temp/temp20151020094428144
     [echo] *****************************************************************

build-init:

preprocess.init:
     [echo] *****************************************************************
     [echo] * input = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/understanding_css.ditamap
     [echo] *****************************************************************

gen-list:

BUILD FAILED
/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/ant_grid_web_css.xml:18: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/build.xml:42: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.base/build_preprocess.xml:78: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dita.dost.module.GenMapAndTopicListModule
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$6.set(IntrospectionHelper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$AttributeSetter.setObject(IntrospectionHelper.java:1493)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper.setAttribute(IntrospectionHelper.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:528)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:464)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChild(UnknownElement.java:592)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.java:358)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.configure(UnknownElement.java:204)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

As you can read from the output above, the error output begins after the "BUILD FAILED" line.

### My troubleshooting attempts

- I found someone else with a similar issue: https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/dita-users/conversations/topics/38045. Yet, when I added the property and set the environment variables up for Saxon, I get the same output.
- I've also tested the other ant script samples in the Open Toolkit and received the same error message.

### Call for help

I think I either set up my environment variables incorrectly, or there's something I can't even imagine causing this issue; hence, I need some extra eyes on this issue.

Accordingly, maybe someone could help walk me through how I am supposed to set up my java + ant + saxon + xalan—I have yet to find good documentation on this process. Plus, how to verify I have everything I need to get this to work. Or, I would love help to see if it's something else.

FYI, I'm using DITA-OT 2.1.1. Here's a link to my topic model on Github: https://github.com/lingeringcode/css-projects.

Any help is appreciated! :-)

### UPDATE

FTR, the `dita` command works with the `-D` args, as follows:

```
:~/dita-ot-2.1.1$ dita -f html5 -i 'projects/css-projects/understanding_css.ditamap' \
    -o 'projects/css-projects/ex-understanding-css' \
    -Dargs.cssroot='projects/css-projects/shared-assets' \
    -Dargs.css='${cssroot}/web-css-grids.css' \
    -Dargs.csspath='css' \
    -Dargs.copycss='yes'
```

I also reset my CLASSPATH variables, making sure the dost.jar was indeed found. After running the ant script again, I received a new `BUILD FAILED` error message (yay, progress?!) as seen below:

```
    lingeringcode@Linger:~/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects$ ant -f '/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/ant_grid_web_css.xml' 
Buildfile: /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/ant_grid_web_css.xml

clean.grids.grid_web_css:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ex-ant-understanding-css

grids.grid_web_css:

init:

dita2html5.init:

check-arg:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ex-ant-understanding-css
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/temp/temp20151022130204394

log-arg:
     [echo] *****************************************************************
     [echo] * basedir = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts
     [echo] * dita.dir = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1
     [echo] * transtype = html5
     [echo] * tempdir = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/temp/temp20151022130204394
     [echo] * outputdir = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ex-ant-understanding-css
     [echo] * clean.temp = true
     [echo] * DITA-OT version = 2.1.1
     [echo] * XML parser = Xerces
     [echo] * XSLT processor = Saxon
     [echo] * collator = JDL
     [echo] *****************************************************************
     [echo] #Ant properties
     [echo] #Thu Oct 22 13:02:05 CDT 2015
     [echo] args.copycss=yes
     [echo] args.css=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/shared-assets/web-css-grids.css
     [echo] args.csspath=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ex-ant-understanding-css/css
     [echo] args.cssroot=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/shared-assets
     [echo] args.grammar.cache=yes
     [echo] args.input=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/understanding_css.ditamap
     [echo] args.logdir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ex-ant-understanding-css
     [echo] args.xml.systemid.set=yes
     [echo] dita.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1
     [echo] dita.plugin.com.sophos.tocjs.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/com.sophos.tocjs
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.base.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.docbook.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.docbook
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.eclipsecontent.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.eclipsecontent
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.eclipsehelp.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.eclipsehelp
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.htmlhelp.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.htmlhelp
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.javahelp.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.javahelp
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.odt.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.odt
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.pdf2.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.pdf2
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.specialization.dita11.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.specialization.dita11
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.specialization.eclipsemap.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.specialization.eclipsemap
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.troff.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.troff
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.wordrtf.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.wordrtf
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.dita.xhtml.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.xhtml
     [echo] dita.plugin.org.oasis-open.dita.v1_2.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.oasis-open.dita.v1_2
     [echo] dita.temp.dir=/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/temp/temp20151022130204394
     [echo] *****************************************************************

build-init:

preprocess.init:
     [echo] *****************************************************************
     [echo] * input = /home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/understanding_css.ditamap
     [echo] *****************************************************************

gen-list:
 [gen-list] Failed to read print transtypes from configuration, using defaults.
 [gen-list] Using Xerces grammar pool for DTD and schema caching.
 [gen-list] Processing file:/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/understanding_css.ditamap

BUILD FAILED
/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/projects/css-projects/ant-scripts/ant_grid_web_css.xml:24: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/build.xml:42: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/lingeringcode/dita-ot-2.1.1/plugins/org.dita.base/build_preprocess.xml:78: Failed to run pipeline: Failed to load messages configuration file: Message configuration file not found
```

Now, it's reporting the "failed pipeline" + failure to load some config file. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you still need help with this? Please, if you get another error, do not update your original question but create a new one. Otherwise nobody is notified.

Comment: Hi, @xephon, thanks for checking back with me. I haven't had time to go back to this particular method. Instead, I used the command-line arguments.

If I do return to this method, I will definitely take this into consideration. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the important information:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dita.dost.module.GenMapAndTopicListModule
```

This indicates that the dost.jar is missing. You have to pass the DITA libraries to Ant, otherwise the script does not work.

You can read in the docs [Building output using Ant](http://www.dita-ot.org/2.1/user-guide/building-with-ant.html) how you should call Ant.

Maybe you do not need to call your transformation with Ant at all. The `dita` command has an `args.css` parameter that probably does what you are trying to achieve. Please have a look at [Ant parameters: Common HTML-based transformations](http://www.dita-ot.org/2.1/parameters/ant-parameters-base-html-transformation.html).

Comment: The dita command works with -D args. Yet, I'd still like to see if I could get ant to work as well.

I redefined my environment variables / class paths for good measure. FTR, I'm following (and modifying) the following documentation from the DITA-OT 1.5.4, because I can't find it for 2.1: [http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/1.5.4/readme/DITA-installation.html](http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/1.5.4/readme/DITA-installation.html). I've modified the CLASSPATH file names to match 2.1.1. Yet, it still isn't finding dost.jar. Do you have a link to updated docs?

Comment: I'm going to tinker around some more with how I set up Ant and Saxon. I'm wondering if I made a misstep somewhere / don't have the latest version, etc.

Thanks for your direction, @xephon!

Comment: I "fixed" the dost.jar error, but have a new one. Any ideas about this "pipeline" error message?

Comment: Hmm... have you read [Installing the distribution package](http://www.dita-ot.org/2.1/getting-started/installing-client.html)?

Comment: The docs say:"Optional: Add the absolute path for the bin directory to the PATH system variable.

This defines the necessary environment variable to run the dita command from the command line.
Tip: This step is recommended, as it allows the the dita command to be run from any location on the file system and makes it easier to transform DITA content from any folder."

Comment: You might want to take a loot at the `startcmd.bat`. This file sets all the needed `CLASSPATH` variables.

Comment: And do not use the old docs. The latest one contains everything you need. The old one may even contain something wrong. There has changed a lot in the meantime. Usually you do not have to set the CLASSPATH by yourself, because the `dita.bat` does that for you. This command has been introduced with DITA-OT 2.x, so the old docs do not mention this command.

Comment: If you do not have a special environment and just want to use a standard DITA environment with windows, forget about the PATH stuff and use the DITA command, as it is explained in [Building output using the dita command](http://www.dita-ot.org/2.1/getting-started/using-dita-command.html).

Comment: I assume that you did not use the `startcmd.bat` command, as it is explained in [Building output using Ant](http://www.dita-ot.org/2.1/user-guide/building-with-ant.html). If you want to call DITA from another terminal, you probably have to set up the CLASSPATH by yourself.

Comment: Didn't know this. Thank you! I'll try it out, and let you know how it works out.

Comment: You're welcome. :) If this has helped you, it would be nice, if you would accept my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Well' I cloned your project and tried to publish the map. The build throws several file not found exceptions. You should validate your project and make sure, that it does not have any errors. If you do not have an XML editor that validates your project, try [oXygen XML](https://www.oxygenxml.com/). It has a trial license.

Comment: Right. It's a mess, but I can fix those errors (and did after your nudge). Thanks for all of your help, @xephon. The dita command works, so I'll just use that for now. If I come up with an ANT-based solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: Hi Chris, maybe the [DITA-OT Ant Task](https://github.com/eerohele/dottask) is interesting for you.